# Python Matplotlib - Formatting numbers in a Chart

Tags: python, dataframe, matplotlib, pycharm, formatting

I have a dataframe where I have formatted the numbers per the snip below, but when I plot this the formatting reverts to scientific. How do I format the chart to match the dataframe? the data type is float64 and I am using Pycharm. My code is below,
Thanks

```
    import pandas as pd
    import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

    gdp2019 = pd.read_csv("GDP2019.csv")
    pd.options.display.float_format = '{:,.2f}'.format
    newDF.plot(x='LOCATION', y='Value', kind='bar')
    plt.show()
```

[image: dataframe image]

[image: Chart image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add this line to your code to get rid of scientific notation on the y axis:

```
plt.ticklabel_format(axis = 'y', style= 'plain')
```

If you want the y-label numbers to be comma_separated and show two decimal points, use this line instead:

```
import matplotlib.ticker as ticker
plt.gca().yaxis.set_major_formatter(ticker.StrMethodFormatter('{x:,.2f}'))
```

Comment: Great thanks - that was straightforward. Is there a way to have comma separating the 1000s? I'm a complete beginner with python, but far as I can see the ticklabel_format method only has scientific or plain styles...

Comment: @xceej Yes.  See my amended answer.